# How to use n-readline along with Express - During first request the data is not available

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, npm

I'm using `n-readline` npm package to read text files from the server.
I have a use case, where I had to read at least **300MB** of data from those text files and will be using `Redis` or `Mongoose` to save around **40mb** of data to be transferred to the **browser** where I use `vue` to process that or load data whenever needed.

Now I'm running into a problem where I'm unable to get the results when I call that function for the first time, if I call that again, the function provides me with results.

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const fs = require('fs');
const NreadLine = require('n-readline');

const app = express();

var asyncres = [];
var lines = []

const upload = multer({ storage });

async function nreadline(){
    let linenumbers = [];
    var rl = new NreadLine({
        filepath: './uploads/6789765/serverout1.txt',
        limit: 50
    });
    await rl.start();
    await rl.on('line', (line, linenumer) => {
        linenumbers.push(linenumer);
    });   
    await rl.on('end', () => {
        console.log('done');
        asyncres = [...linenumbers];
    });
    //This is where I'm expecting the results to be returned
    return asyncres;   
}

function getresults() {
    let ress = nreadline();
    console.log(ress);
    return ress;
}

// Express APIs defined below
app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    res.json({ "status": "success", file: req.file });
});

// API for multiple form upload
app.post('/multiple', upload.array('files'), (req, res) => {
    // ticket = req.body.ticket
    res.json({ "status": "success", files: req.files });
});

//Get Request for reading the files
app.get('/reader', (req, res) => {
    let results = getresults();
    res.json({ "status": results });
});

app.listen(port, () => { 
    console.log("running on 3344 port");
});
```

Please Help. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: just trying to understand, why do you have     `await res.json({"status": results})`
on endpoint `/reader`...

Can it not be `res.json({"status": results})` ??

Comment: I assumed that the function nreadline would return a promise, hence I converted that to async function so that I would wait for the package to completely read the text file. Am I doing it wrong? @hafizali

Comment: `/reader` endpoint, you arent doing anything with `nreadline` function, `getresults` is the one you are dealing with as `nreadline`  is dealth by `getresults`.

remove await from `await res.json({"status": results})` and it shouldnt change anything for you. 

just one less mistake if it doesnt solve your problem

Comment: adding or removing it from the /reader is not making any difference. But, if I call that end point twice, I'm getting results. Not sure if this helps. @hafizali

Comment: if its not making any difference, remove await from there because it may be doing nothing but creating more confusion.

to make it easy for others to reproduce, why not add it to codesandbox to reproduce as there seems to be good number of moving parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I found another npm package, that kinda solves my problem.

The package name is n-readlines and below the code that I modified.

```
const lineByLine = require('n-readlines');

function nreadline(filePath){
let logs = [];
try{
    let rl = new lineByLine('./uploads/6789765/serverout0.txt');
    let line;
    while(line=rl.next()){
        logs.push(line.toString('utf8'));
    }
return logs;

}catch(err){

}
```